# Naming attribute in Angular custom components: with or without hyphen?

Tags: html, angular, attributes, components, custom-component

I have created an Angular component that have some inputs, such as the following:

`@Input('max-length') maxLength: number;`

So when I use it from another component I can type this:

`<my-component max-length="{{lengthValue}}"></my-component>`

or

`<my-component [max-length]="lengthValue"></my-component>`

Is this compliant with HTML standard?

Maybe I could prefix it with `data-` to be fully compliant:

`@Input('data-max-length') maxLength: number;`

So I can use it in the following way:

`<my-component data-max-length="{{lengthValue}}"></my-component>`

Ok, but what about the [Angular best practice](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-13) that suggests input bindings should not be aliased?

Comment: Why do you want to alias this input? It's bad practice, unless you hace a good reason for it.

Comment: I said the same at the end of my question! I'm asking how to have HTML compliant attributes in my components...

Comment: In this case, your are working with Angular. As you said, it is better to avoid alliasing input bindings. It will be more readeable for other user that are used to Angular. When using data-...., it is like your are doing something outside angular.
Maybe if you use your component as custom elements (outside Angular environment) it could be a good idea.